# How can i solve duplication of code in this?

Tags: java

I want to check if all the ingredients(toppings and fillings) inside a wrap are both vegan and nut free. This is the solution that I came up with, howver I think its a bit inefficient as there is duplication of code. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

(I have a map for all the toppings and fillings which every one contains boolean to know if the topping/filling is vegan and if it is nut free.

```
public boolean isVegan() {
    for (Topping t : toppings) {
        if (!t.isVegan()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (Filling f : fillings) {
        if (!f.isVegan()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return bread.isVegan();
}

public boolean isNutFree() {
    for (Topping t : toppings) {
        if (!t.isNutFree()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (Filling f : fillings) {
        if (!f.isNutFree()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return bread.isNutFree();
}
```

Comment: Are you able to use java 8?

Comment: @SamzSakerz yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing that `Ingredient` is the base class of these different classes and that this class defines the `isVegan()` method, you could create a Stream from all these objects and computing whether all are vegan :

```
public boolean isVegan() {
    return 
    Stream.concat(toppings.stream(), fillings.stream(), Stream.of(bread))
          .allMatch(Ingredient::isVegan);

}
```

For `isNutFree()` the idea is the same :

```
public boolean isNutFree() {
    return 
    Stream.concat(toppings.stream(), fillings.stream(), Stream.of(bread))
          .allMatch(Ingredient::isNutFree);

}
```

Note that you could also generalize a matching method to reduce further the duplication :

```
public boolean allMatch(Predicate<Ingredient> predicate) {
    return 
    Stream.concat(toppings.stream(), fillings.stream(), Stream.of(bread))
          .allMatch( i -> predicate.test(i));

}
```

And use it such as :

```
boolean isNutFree = allMatch(Ingredient::isNutFree);
boolean isVegan =  allMatch(Ingredient::isVegan);
```

Comment: @SamzSakerz If you have some interesting ideas as variants, don't hesitate :)

Comment: Was writing a code with filters/length, But yours is way better

Answer (score 2):

Here is a food type replacing either Topping or Filling or anything:

```
public interface FoodPart {

    boolean isVegan();

    boolean isNutFree();

}
```

Here we have an abstract Food class containing all common codes:

```
public abstract class Food {

    private List<? extends FoodPart> foodParts;

    public boolean isVegan() {
        return foodParts.stream().noneMatch(foodPart -> foodPart.isVegan());
    }

    public boolean isNutFree() {
        return foodParts.stream().noneMatch(foodPart -> foodPart.isNutFree());
    }

}
```

And here is a concrete and *not* abstract food:

```
public class Lasagne extends Food {}
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want to inherit from FoodPart then you can change `List<? extends FoodPart>` simply to `List<FoodPart>`.

You can also make Food to not abstract so you can easily use it, and don't forget to add getters/setters to provide the `foodParts`.

Answer (score 2):

Yeez, you guys are fast :)

What I wrote is pretty much already covered in the other answers here but just posting since mine does have some subtle differences (not necessarily better). And since I already went through the motions of writing the code I might as well post it :)

First an interface for your fillings and toppings:

```
public interface FoodInformation {
    boolean isVegan();
    boolean isNutFree();
    boolean isGlutenFree();
}
```

Then an abstract class which your toppings and fillings can extend:

```
public abstract class Ingredient implements FoodInformation {
    private boolean vegan;
    private boolean nutFree;
    private boolean glutenFree;

    public Ingredient(boolean vegan, boolean nutFree, boolean glutenFree) {
        this.vegan = vegan;
        this.nutFree = nutFree;
        this.glutenFree = glutenFree;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isVegan() {
        return vegan;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNutFree() {
        return nutFree;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isGlutenFree() {
        return glutenFree;
    }
}
```

Your Filling:

```
public class Filling extends Ingredient {
    public Filling(boolean vegan, boolean nutFree, boolean glutenFree) {
        super(vegan, nutFree, glutenFree);
    }
}
```

Your Topping:

```
public class Topping extends Ingredient {
    public Topping(boolean vegan, boolean nutFree, boolean glutenFree) {
        super(vegan, nutFree, glutenFree);
    }
}
```

And your Wrap:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Wrap {
    private List<Filling> fillings;
    private List<Topping> toppings;

    public Wrap(List<Filling> fillings, List<Topping> toppings) {
        this.fillings = fillings;
        this.toppings = toppings;
    }

    public boolean isNutFree() {
        return testIngredient(FoodInformation::isNutFree);
    }

    public boolean isVegan() {
        return testIngredient(FoodInformation::isVegan);
    }

    public boolean isGlutenFree() {
        return testIngredient(FoodInformation::isGlutenFree);
    }

    private boolean testIngredient(Predicate<FoodInformation> predicate) {
        // edited thanks to davidxxx for the Stream.concat notation!
        return Stream
                .concat(fillings.stream(), toppings.stream())
                .allMatch(predicate);
    }
}
```

And a test to show the implementation works:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;

public class WrapTest {
    private Wrap wrap;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Filling filling1 = new Filling(true, true, false);
        Filling filling2 = new Filling(true, false, true);
        Filling filling3 = new Filling(true, true, true);

        Topping topping1 = new Topping(true, true, true);

        wrap = new Wrap(Arrays.asList(filling1, filling2, filling3), Collections.singletonList(topping1));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsGlutenFree() {
        assertFalse(wrap.isGlutenFree());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsNutFree() {
        assertFalse(wrap.isNutFree());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsVegan() {
        assertTrue(wrap.isVegan());
    }
}
```

Have fun with your project!

Comment: Good solution, I think in this case FoodInformation interface is unneseccary since you have Ingredient.

Answer (score 1):

create an interface that has isVegan and isNutFree

```
public interface MyInterface {
    boolean isVegan();
    boolean isNutFree();
}
```

Then each of your classes with implement your interface

```
public class Topping implements MyInterface {

    @Override    
    public boolean isVegan() {
       return isVegan;
    }

    @Override boolean isNutFree() {
        return isNutFree;
    }
}

public class Filling implements MyInterface {

    @Override    
    public boolean isVegan() {
       return isVegan;
    }

    @Override boolean isNutFree() {
        return isNutFree;
    }
}
```

Next create a method that can test the lists

```
public boolean isVegan(List<? extends MyInterface> list) {
   for(MyInterface myObj : list) {
      if (myObj.isVegan()) return true;
   }
   return false;
}

public boolean isNutFree(List<? extends MyInterface> list) {
   for(MyInterface myObj: list) {
      if (myObj.isNutFree()) return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

then each list you can pass into the methods to get the results